# Coordicide Whitepaper Jan 2020, Mana System, Averaged Mana

Tags: white-paper

In coordicide whitepaper in section 3.3 the mana system is introduced. It is stated that an averaged version of mana will be used. While I think I understand the necessity to use the averaged mana I wonder how this affects malicious nodes.

- Do malicious nodes lose their averaged mana immediately?
- Or do they lose their mana and because of that also their averaged mana but slowly? How are malicious nodes prevented from sending further transactions in this case?
- Or something else?